# Using flyway command line to version indexes

Tags: java, sql-server, migration, flyway

Here is my scenario, I'm a DBA and received the mission of creating an bitbucket repostiroy with CI to control all procedures and functions in SQL Server.
This first step was successfully completed through flyway 5.2.4 with repetitive scripts Repeatable.

Now i'm trying to extend the project to control only the indexes.

Some projects implement flyway or other migrations solutions and some do not implement. So I would like to control the indices in this same project.

My question is it's possible, the flyway documentation is not clear, I'm also try to use the NTV__ scripts but doesn't work.

Has anyone tried this before? Am I asking for something impossible?

`conf file`

```
flyway.url=jdbc:sqlserver://select:1433;databaseName=database
flyway.user=sa
flyway.password=pass
flyway.locations=filesystem:/home/krismorte/repo/DOCKER/flyway-teste/
flyway.sqlMigrationSuffixes=.sql
flyway.table=flyway_my_sql_objects
flyway.baselineOnMigrate=true
flyway.allowMixedMigrations = true
```

repeatable file

```
CREATE OR ALTER PROCEDURE [DBA].[USP_UPDATESTATISTICS] @RUN INT = 0
--  WITH ENCRYPTION
AS
BEGIN

SET NOCOUNT ON;

DECLARE 
    @TOP                INT = 200,              -- QUANTOS INDEXES SERÃO EFETUADOS O REBUILD POR VEZ
    @WINDOW_LIMIT       DATETIME = '06:00:00',  -- VALOR DO HORÁRIO LIMITE DA JANELA EX: '13:32:00'
    @STR_UPDATESTATS    NVARCHAR(MAX) = '',
    @ID                 INT,
    @TIME               DATETIME

SELECT TOP (@TOP)
     ID = IDENTITY(INT, 1, 1)
    ,DATABASENAME = DB_NAME()
    ,TABLENAME = O.NAME
INTO #STATISTICSTOUPDATE
FROM SYS.OBJECTS O
WHERE OBJECTPROPERTY(O.[OBJECT_ID], 'ISMSSHIPPED') = 0
    AND O.TYPE_DESC = 'USER_TABLE'
ORDER BY [TABLENAME]  DESC

WHILE EXISTS(SELECT TOP 1 1 FROM #STATISTICSTOUPDATE)
BEGIN   
    SELECT TOP 1 
        @ID = ID,
        @TIME = CONVERT(VARCHAR(8),DATEADD(HOUR, -3, GETDATE()),108) ,
        @STR_UPDATESTATS = '
        SET ANSI_PADDING ON;
        UPDATE STATISTICS [' + I.TABLENAME + '] WITH FULLSCAN;
        SET ANSI_PADDING OFF;' 
    FROM #STATISTICSTOUPDATE I;     

    IF (@WINDOW_LIMIT IS NULL OR @TIME < @WINDOW_LIMIT)
    BEGIN
        BEGIN TRY
            PRINT 'EXECUTANDO: ' + @STR_UPDATESTATS + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10);  

            IF @RUN = 1
             EXEC (@STR_UPDATESTATS);   

            INSERT INTO [DBA].[LOGUPDATESTATISTICS] ([DATA], [DATABASE], [TABLE_NAME], [SCRIPT_REBUILD], [STATUS]) 
            SELECT @TIME, I.DATABASENAME, I.TABLENAME, @STR_UPDATESTATS, 'OK' FROM #STATISTICSTOUPDATE I WHERE ID = @ID;    
        END TRY
        BEGIN CATCH
            INSERT INTO [DBA].[LOGUPDATESTATISTICS] ([DATA], [DATABASE], [TABLE_NAME], [SCRIPT_REBUILD], [STATUS], [ERROR_MESSAGE]) 
            SELECT @TIME, I.DATABASENAME, I.TABLENAME, @STR_UPDATESTATS, 'OK', ERROR_MESSAGE() FROM #STATISTICSTOUPDATE I WHERE ID = @ID;
        END CATCH
    END
    DELETE FROM #STATISTICSTOUPDATE WHERE ID = @ID;
END


DROP TABLE #STATISTICSTOUPDATE;
END
GO
```

No TYransaction file

```
create index ix_teste on [DBO].Table_EXTRACAO_10 (marketplace);
```

The repeatable works fine but the no native doesn't, I've already tryed to change the name to V_

Comment: Each application needs to handle its own Flyway migrations, if it is using Flyway or some other DB versioning framework.

Comment: @ManoDestra I totally agree with you, but in this case it is a legacy and sharing bank. We are already working to break it into micro services. But for now I want to centralize some common actions like procedures and indeces.

Comment: What you CAN do, albeit unorthodox, is use a differently named schema_version table for your migrations only. That way you avoid conflict with versioning including other flyway migrations.

Comment: Yes, i'm using a custom table name, but the version script with the index command is ignored by the flyway with no error or warning message.

Comment: Can you include the script for that migration?

Comment: @ManoDestra I add more information about my case

Comment: What errors do you get when you run the create-index migration?

Comment: @JuliaHayward this is the strange part, there's no error. Looks like that the file is ignored by flyway migrate

Comment: You mentioned changing the filename to V_ - what filename were you using before? What's the output of `flyway info` ?

Comment: I saw in another question  that indexes must be created without transaction with the NTV_ prefix I tryed both and still the R_

Comment: Could you give a link to that question? My installation (5.2.4) doesn't recognise scripts with prefix NTV_

Comment: ... because it wasn't a mainstream feature and was not merged in https://github.com/flyway/flyway/pull/1027